# Really Invisible WiFi (not just hidden)

Tags: ieee-802.11

I want my WiFi to be invisible to anyone, and I don't mean hidden. I know about the hidden SSID method, but in this method the network is visible like "hidden network". I would like to create a really hidden network, visible only to me in someway. Is it possible?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?  If you want to insure that people can't eavesdrop, current encryption is good enough.  You can use strong authentication to insure that only you can connect to your network.  But if you don't want anyone to know that you are using Wi-Fi...that's impossible.  It's like hiding the fact that you are using a flashlight in a dark room -- everyone will see you.

Comment: The construction of a basic Faraday cage ought to work!

Comment: rnxrx you're a genius! how did I not think about that? that is the reason why I posted this, fresh ideas. Thanks mate

Ron you're right about that, I just thought if there was a way, to connect only specific clients, and somehow transmit only to them (stupid I know :D)

Comment: Ron, I just want to create a network that someone near me won't be able to see. Someone specifically :)

Comment: MIT researchers decode audio from a potato chip bag in a video. http://news.mit.edu/2014/algorithm-recovers-speech-from-vibrations-0804

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi WiFi network as it names says is wireless, you can't hide it.

1. There is few options you can do like disable beacon frame broadcast. 
   Than you won't be able to discovery network SSID. But packets will be still sent and simple WiFi scan would find your network SSID.
2. You can decrease TX/RC power to make it range shorter just to cover chosen area.
3. Modification of frequency spectrum that WiFi client and AP is working on different than assigned frequencies (2.4,  5) but it would be more likely illegal to use different range. It as well not hiding your network but moving it to different frequency and with proper tools you would be able to see packets flowing.

Comment: The correct Wi-Fi channels in the 2.4GHz band are 1, 6, and 11

Comment: Ron I was talking about frequencies change to be different than standard assigned channel. So no other clients can see communication.

Comment: Moving to other channels like 2,4 or 5 would not be very effective, since all WI-Fi devices will scan all channels.  Also, any WI-fi tool like Netstumbler would easily find it.

Comment: Ron I was thinking to change frequency out of scope for 802.11a or 802.11b. For exmaple channel 14 for 802.11a is 2484Mhz so if you will be able to change frequency to 2500Mhz  non of device would be able to see packets which you transmuting. But client and AP would need to work on same frequency. It's bit tricky but could be done.

Comment: Datagram,Network how do I decrease TX/RC power? by software or hardware? Thanks for your answer anyway, nice ideas

Comment: I misread your answer. I saw 2,4,5 instead of 2.4,5.   Ignore my original comment.

Comment: Depends of the platform usually you have settings in software. Please refer to manual of you device.

Comment: @Datagram.Network I'm curious to understand more about your answer. Does the standard Wi-Fi chipsets like Quantenna,Broadcom support this type of change on the radio? If Understand correctly,You will need the underlying PHY support to change the frequency to 2484 to 2500. Could you please explain more on this?

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to accomplish is not really feasible. As Wi-Fi uses radio waves, they will propagate to the environment. Really, the only way to prevent others from seeing your Wi-Fi is an RF-insulated room (implemented using a Faraday cage -- you need to take into account the wavelength of Wi-Fi signals if using a net instead of using solid metal). Such rooms are very common in companies that do radio wave related work. Oh, and your mobile phone will not work in such a room.

May I suggest a wired network instead? You can hide your wired network extremely well: in theory, there may be some emissions from twisted pair cables, but in practice nobody with an ordinary computer will see that you have a wired network. If your enemy is an intelligence agency, then you should consider reading the Wikipedia article on TEMPEST.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there are a couple of ways to go about this.

1.Buy some Japaneese equipment and use channel 14 at low power - you
   may bleed onto ch. 11 a little bit, but they will have to be very
   close.  -- not legal of course

2. Get some 4.8 GHz Public Safety WiFi equipment. -- not legal of course
3. Go find some old FHSS adapters.  -- 1 Mb/s isn't that bad.
4. Use Bluetooth.  Hardly anyone looks for that.
5. Totally re-write the wifi-driver software to change the checksum method and everyone else will drop your packets.